# How to define XML schema for tags with parameters?

Tags: xml, tags

I know how to define an xml schema for simple entities within tags. How can we define xml schema for tags with parameters ?

```
<logins>
<login type="uname" value="robert"/>
<login type="name"  value="robert williams" />
</login>
```

I know

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema>
    <xs: element name="login">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>

         <!-- What will come here ??-->
       </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name ="loginType">
    <xs:attribute name ="name" type ="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name ="value" type ="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name ="loginsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="login" type ="loginType" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name ="logins" type ="loginsType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: +1 for the precise answer. Can you point to some good tutorials for XML schema? I found few but they were insufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not remember a favorite.
A little more patience and Mr Google will give an answer :)